# Is there a better way to access parent's variables from a child class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have the following code:

```
class PhysicalObject {
public:
    double x, y, mass, airrescons, volume;
    bool grav, airres, buoy;
    Vector2d velocity;
    // ...
    // Here I define some physics methods
    // ...
}

class Ball : public PhysicalObject {
    double radius;
public:
    Ball() {
        PhysicalObject::x = 0;
        PhysicalObject::y = 0;
        radius = 1;
        PhysicalObject::mass = 1;
        PhysicalObject::grav = true;
        PhysicalObject::airres = true;
        PhysicalObject::buoy = true;
        PhysicalObject::airrescons = circcons*airden*PI*radius/mass;
        PhysicalObject::volume = PI*radius*radius;
        PhysicalObject::velocity = Vector2d();
    };
    // ...
    // More physics methods defined here
    // ...
}
```

Since I want to keep those variables at `PhysicalObject` class, because it has generic methods and children classes that use them, I wonder if there is a way to import those variables to a child class, like `Ball`, and tell the program that, for example, every time I use the variable `mass` at Ball's scope I'm refering to `PhysicalObject::mass`, that way I avoid using `PhysicalObject::` several times throughout Ball's methods.

If I declare them at `Ball`, I get two different variables, `Ball::mass` and `PhysicalObject::mass` for example, but I want them to be the same.

I thought about using pointers that point to PhysicalObject's variables inside Ball, so I get smaller variable names, but I don't want to declare all variables again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do this:

```
class Ball : public PhysicalObject {
public:
    Ball() {
        this->x = 0;
        this->y = 0;
```

Or this:

```
class Ball : public PhysicalObject {
public:
    using PhysicalObject::x;
    using PhysicalObject::y;
    Ball() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
```

In the specific example you posted, with no templates involved, you don't even need to do `using`:

```
class Ball : public PhysicalObject {
public:
    Ball() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
```

But since you asked this question I assume your real code doesn't work with such a solution--perhaps because it uses templates which have different lookup rules.

Comment: Actually something strange happened. Before I asked the question I tried the last option you suggested, and it didn't work, because the compiler said that the class Ball doesn't have variables named x or y. Now I tried it again and it worked well. Thanks for the help dude :D